# how to remove decimal value from product price Magento 2?

Tags: price, magento-2.1.8

The price-utils.js solution did not work for me.

I have changed from  `const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 2;` To `const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 0;` in  `/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/PriceCurrencyInterface.php`

but, it is working only on the product listing page. I want to remove precision from the entire site.

Comment: I tried this [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150721/changing-the-display-of-custom-product-price-to-show-4-decimal-places?rq=1) and works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Please Check https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal Extension. I think it'll help you.

Comment: it is working fine for frontend but creating the issue within admin. 
When we save product in admin, it is change price after comma.
for ex: 7,499 changed to 7

Comment: We have tried this and it's working properly for us. I don't know why it causes an issue in your backend.

Comment: Then please check the answer on https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/150788/17154

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.  thank you so much for sharing.. life gone easy with that plugin.. :)