# Where does the price precision come from?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, price, checkout-summary

I have my **Magento 2.2.6** webshop set up **locally** (development mode) and on the server (**production mode**). On my local installation the cart summary shows a precision of **2 decimals**, on my server it shows a **precision of 1**. Where does this come from? How come they are not the same?

Comment: Check this if you have help full.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150721/changing-the-display-of-custom-product-price-to-show-4-decimal-places

Comment: Extension for price precision:
https://marketplace.magento.com/lillik-module-price-decimal.html

Comment: thanks. I don't want to change it. In the first place I'd like to understand why on two different installations of the same shop with the same configuration, the precision is different.

Comment: So, I figured out that it has something to do with intl NumberFormatter behaving differently on my local system vs. my server running CentOS 6. So I ended up using the above mentioned plugin to make sure the precision is the same on all systems.