# Magento 2.2.x How to remove MSRP decimals in Admin catalog product grid?

Tags: magento2, price, admin-panel, product-grid, msrp

I'm trying to find how to format prices in Magento 2 but stuck with MSRP. In Admin Product Grid, it has 4 decimals. When Editing product, msrp price is correctly currency formatted. Can you guys hint me where to look at to resolve this?

Comment: Do you mean the decimal places? Check if there's some override as by default there should be two decimal places. More here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150721/changing-the-display-of-custom-product-price-to-show-4-decimal-places

Comment: Hi, yep I mean the decimal places of msrp but in Admin > Catalog > Product grid. It shows 4 decimals. I'm trying to find where to modify this.

Comment: Finally, I made it work using some of other's technique https://github.com/VaporFan/admin-product-grid-format-msrp

Comment: Glad you got it working!