# Magento 2: How to change price formatting for the API interface?

Tags: magento2, api, soap

I need for the (soap) sales order API all prices with 4 decimal places.

**Example:**

```
9.45 => 9.4500
```

But only for the API not for other prices! I know the prices are already stored with 4 decimal places in the database. But I have no idea how I can change the API output.

Thank you and regards,
Michael

Comment: try to override the interface of the required API and create your own class and in your class change the format of the price . In case of soap, override this file in webapi_soap folder and it will work for soap only.

Comment: Thank you that helping me for the first step. But now I have the problem that in the order class all price getter methods already output with 2 decimal places. I can not find where it is changed from 4 to 2 decimal places. Because in the database it is stored with 4 decimal places.

Comment: can you check this solution. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150721/changing-the-display-of-custom-product-price-to-show-4-decimal-places/150788

Comment: Thanks for you help. But the solution is very easy because the outputs are already with 4 decimal places. But float cut the trailing zeros. In Magento 1 it was not cutted but I think that a all Strings which are outputed.