# Price format count in upto 4 decimal points but display 2 decimal points in frontend

Tags: magento2, price, special-price

I want to display price in two decimal points.

If I enter **38.3445** in special price than I want output in frontend as **38.35** or **38.00** . But Magento display as **38.34** . Magento counts upto 3 decimal points. But I want to make it count upto 4.

Same as I enter **38.4945** than I want output as **38.50 or 39.00** But magento display as **38.49**.

I make following changes in 4 files to set 4 decimal points:-

1 File : m229/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Currency.php:
Line no 74 set this  : `'precision' => 4,`

2 file : m229/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/PriceCurrencyInterface.php  : line no 19 : `const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 4;`

3 file : m229/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php : line no 280 : `return $this->formatPrecision($price, 4, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);`

4 file : m229/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php : line no 1711 : replace this function :

```
public function formatPrice($price, $addBrackets = false)
    {
        return $this->formatPricePrecision($price, 4, $addBrackets);
    }
```

Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you in advance...

Comment: you can use this extension : https://github.com/karliuka/m2.Price

Comment: Its not working as i mansion in question. by the way thanks for your reply.

Comment: hope this help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150721/changing-the-display-of-custom-product-price-to-show-4-decimal-places/150788

Comment: Its not working bro. Magento counts upto 3 decimal points and increment into 2 digit. But I want to count it to 4 to 3, and 3 to 2 and 2 to 1. And according to this price will be change.