# how to Remove the decimal number from price in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, price

We want to Remove the decimal number from price in Magento 2.3  ex. **100.00$** to be **100$**.

Anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to remove it in all pages where the price is displayed?

Comment: I think these 4 files to edit will help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291695/price-format-count-in-upto-4-decimal-points-but-display-2-decimal-points-in-fron

Comment: Yes i want this all pages

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-utils.js` and change the value of precision on **line 38**:

from

```
var precision = isNaN(format.requiredPrecision = Math.abs(format.requiredPrecision)) ? 2 : format.requiredPrecision,
```

to

```
var precision = 0,
```

Or using number_format or round funciton of php like this:

> $price = 100.00; number_format($price, 0, '.', ''); result : 100

For more please check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122808/magento-2-how-to-remove-price-decimal):

or use this extension:  https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal