# Magento 2 Swiss Currency Decimal digit Issue on Staging server only

Tags: magento2.3, price

We have multi-stores on our server in Magento 2.3.1 
There is a currency format issue on the server only on cart success page and checkout page. We have Swiss currency setup and Decimal digit is showing only one number like - **CHF 123.0** (On cart summary and checkout page only)

Expected currency format **CHF 123.00**

[image]
Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you use any extension or change in currency format ?

Comment: @PradipGarchar No. I am using default configurations only. The problem is, currency format is wrong on cart summary and checkout page only. Also the stupid thing is, on the local machine, it is working quite fine.

Comment: I think you have to change in this four files. Look at this question. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291695/price-format-count-in-upto-4-decimal-points-but-display-2-decimal-points-in-fron

Comment: @ChiragParmar The problem is, currency format looks good rest of other areas excluding the cart summary section and checkout page. It won't work. Also the strange thing is, this issue doesn't arrive on my local machine setup. Is this server related issues??

Comment: @ChiragParmar Might be the issue.